# Server Side Response Caching (Cloudflare)

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, cloudflare

How can we cache the response of a .NET Core API in Cloudflare?

I used the following Attribute with the controller action I need to cache, but this makes the response to be cached in the browser as well.

```
    `[ResponseCache(Duration = 120, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, NoStore = false)]`
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can we cache the response of a .NET Core API in Cloudflare?

Accroding to your scenario, it would nicer, if you could have shared more insight. So that it can be investigate accrodingly.

However, in general using caching attributes directly on your controller actions in .NET Core will cache the response in the browser as well as Cloudflare.

First of all, Enable "Origin Cache Control" in your Cloudflare settings.

In your .NET Core API, set appropriate Cache-Control headers in the response to instruct Cloudflare on caching behavior.

For instance, you could set the `Cache-Control header` to control how Cloudflare caches the response.
In the controller action, you can add the `[ResponseCache]` attribute with the appropriate cache duration and settings.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
   
}
```

In addition, make sure that the Cache-Control header is set properly in your API responses. You can do this by setting the Cache-Control header in your response like below:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=60");
```

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/set-caching-levels/), which might be resourceful for you.